# ObservableCollection + RaiseEvent on Add

Tags: c#

HI all,

How can I raise an event on when an item is added to an ObservableCollection?

Answer (score 9):

CollectionChanged gets fired when an item is added, removed, changed, moved, or the entire list is refreshed.  You can subscribe to CollectionChanged to receive notifications.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)

```
 public class NameList : ObservableCollection<PersonName>
    {
        public NameList() : base()
        {
            Add(new PersonName("Willa", "Cather"));
            Add(new PersonName("Isak", "Dinesen"));
            Add(new PersonName("Victor", "Hugo"));
            Add(new PersonName("Jules", "Verne"));
        }
      }

      public class PersonName
      {
          private string firstName;
          private string lastName;

          public PersonName(string first, string last)
          {
              this.firstName = first;
              this.lastName = last;
          }

          public string FirstName
          {
              get { return firstName; }
              set { firstName = value; }
          }

          public string LastName
          {
              get { return lastName; }
              set { lastName = value; }
          }
      }
```

Comment: seconds in it... both Jon and me have "not quite quick enough" deleted answers ;-p

Comment: Answering faster than Marc and Jon –  that should at least be a silver badge!